# How to summarize factor data in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set `train` consisting of a column of dates `obs_m`, a column of factors `default_flag` (levels 0 and 1), and a column of numeric values `pred_default`. When I try to summarize by date using the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
train %>% group_by(obs_m) %>% summarise_at(vars(default_flag, pred_default), mean)
```

It gives me the this:

```
## # A tibble: 60 × 3
##    obs_m      default_flag pred_default
##    <date>            <dbl>        <dbl>
##  1 2014-04-01           NA       0.0169
##  2 2014-05-01           NA       0.0205
##  3 2014-06-01           NA       0.0239
##  4 2014-07-01           NA       0.0246
##  5 2014-08-01           NA       0.0275
##  6 2014-09-01           NA       0.0301
##  7 2014-10-01           NA       0.0291
##  8 2014-11-01           NA       0.0254
##  9 2014-12-01           NA       0.0233
## 10 2015-01-01           NA       0.0199
## # … with 50 more rows
```

What can I do to prevent `default_flag` from returning `NA`s?

#### Edit

```
 train = structure(list(obs_m = structure(c(16161, 16161, 16161, 16161, 
 16161, 16161), class = "Date"), default_flag = structure(c(1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
     pred_default = c(0.0181536124206322, 0.0138495688337231, 
     0.00682555751527574, 0.0107712925780696, 0.0159171589457986, 
     0.0168013691030077)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share a sample dataset? it will help us detect where the problem is

Comment: Do you need to summarize per date / flag? Than it is `train %>% group_by(obs_m, default_flag) %>% summarise_at(vars(pred_default), mean)`.  Otherwise you the mean of the flags would be 0.5 if you remove the factor part of it. Don't think that would be correct.

Comment: @phiver I need to summarize both variables by date, and no, the mean of `flag` would not be 0.5 if we turn it into numeric, the number of 1s is far less than the number of 0s.

Comment: why don't you turn it into numeric and then call mean?

Comment: I could do that, but I am using the factor variable in a model, and changing it into numeric might distort the model outcome.

Comment: so create a new temporary variable which is numeric, call mean on that. You can't call mean on a factor, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @dash2 I already did that, thank you.

Comment: Have you already tried the builtin functions `summary` and `str`, which handle all (I think) data types?